# if element does not exist continue performing actions until element does exist

Tags: cypress

I am new to cypress and i have been task with developing a few options to showcase the best way to do UI automation testing for a specific type of work. the test requires to drill down through a map from a top level and it keeps drilling down until a button is visible. once the button is visible it should be pressed to continue to the next part of the workflow

I am using cypress to construct the test and have read through all there documents and researched for an answer to see if anyone has done this prior and got it work. had no luck

i have tried a couple things such as

```
if(cy.get('span[class="mat-button-wrapper"]').contains("Reserve").should('not.be.visible')){
                flag = false
                cy.get('span[class="mat-button-wrapper"]').contains("Reserve").click()
            }
            else{
                flag = true
                cy.wait(100)
            }
```

and also something like

```
cy.get('span[class="mat-button-wrapper"]').contains("Reserve").should('be.visible').then((button)=> {

                 if(button){
                     cy.get('span[class="mat-button-wrapper"]').contains("Reserve").click()
                     flag = true
                 }
             })
```

all im trying to do is have a conditional check to see if the button exists, if it does click the button else continue the while loop

Comment: Have you read the Cypress page on [Conditional Testing](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/conditional-testing.html)? There are better ways to do what you're trying to do, like setting up a known state before the test - then you know exactly how many times to click.

Also, fyi - Cypress commands execute asynchronously, so trying to use a construct like `if(cy.get(...` will never work.

Answer (score 0):

bro.
You can try this code.

```
cy.get('span')
  .should(($span) => {
    expect($span).to.have.length(1)

    const className = $span[0].className

    expect(className).to.match(/mat-button-wrapper/)
  })
  .then(...)
```

Cypress will automatically retry the `should` callback function until it passes or the command times out.

cypress doc: [cypress should callback](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/assertions.html#Should-callback)

Comment: Thaks for the answer but its still lacking the ability to contiune drilling down into a map. like i am trying to get all elements on a map that are "circle" then click one at random, after look to see if a button exists if not scan the page for more circle elements that lead furture into the drill down, check if a button exists after clicking on a circle element and so on. something this drill down will be 4. 5. 6 iterations its all dependent on were the map starts